# How can I generate a new column to group by membership in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['John','Fred','John','George','Fred']})
```

How can I transform this to generate a new column giving me group membership by value? Such that:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['John','Fred','John','George','Fred'], 'group':[1,2,1,3,2]})
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
df['group'] = pd.factorize(df['name'])[0] + 1
print (df)
     name  group
0    John      1
1    Fred      2
2    John      1
3  George      3
4    Fred      2
```